# Understanding algorithm design techniques in depth

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, backtracking, greedy, divide-and-conquer

"Designing the right algorithm for a given application is a difficult job. It requires a major creative act, taking a problem and pulling a solution out of the ether. This is much more difficult than taking someone else's idea and modifying it or tweaking it to make it a little better. The space of choices you can make in algorithm design is enormous, enough to leave you plenty of freedom to hang yourself".

I have studied several basic design techniques of algorithms like Divide and Conquer, Dynamic Programming, greedy, backtracking etc.

But i always fail to recognize what principles to apply when i come across certain programming problems. I want to master the designing of algorithms.

So can any one suggest a best place to understand the principles of algorithm design in depth.....

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Programming Pearls, 2nd edition, by Jon Bentley. He talks a lot about algorithm design techniques and provides examples of real world problems, how they were solved, and how different algorithms affected the runtime.

Throughout the book, you learn algorithm design techniques, program verification methods to ensure your algorithms are correct, and you also learn a little bit about data structures. It's a very good book and I recommend it to anyone who wants to master algorithms. Go read the reviews in amazon: [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Pearls-2nd-Edition-Bentley/dp/0201657880](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201657880)

You can have a look at some of the book's contents here: http://netlib.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You can't learn algorithm design just from reading books. Certainly, books can help. Books like *Programming Pearls* as suggested in another answer are great because they give you problems to work. Each problem forces you to think about how to solve a particular type of problem.

The idea is that you expose yourself to many different types of problems and their solutions. In doing so, you learn how to examine a problem and see if it shares anything in common with problems you've already seen. In that regard, it's not a whole lot different than the way you learned how to solve "word problems" in math class. Granted, most algorithm problems are more complex than having to figure out where on the tracks the two trains will collide, but the way you learn how to solve the problems is the same. You learn common techniques used to solve simple problems, then combine those techniques to solve more complex problems, etc.

Read, practice, lather, rinse, repeat.

In addition to books like *Programming Pearls*, there are sites online that post different programming challenges that you can test yourself on. It helps if you have friends or co-workers who also are interested in algorithms, because you can bounce ideas off each other and pose interesting challenges, or work together to come up with solutions to problems.

Did I mention that it takes practice?

"Mastering" anything takes time. A long time. A popular theory is that it takes 10,000 hours of practice to become an expert at anything. There's some dispute about that for particular endeavors, but in general it's true. You don't master anything overnight. You have to study. And practice. And read what others have done. Study some more and practice some more.

Answer (score 0):

A good book about algorithm design is [Kleinbeg Tardos](http://www.aw-bc.com/info/kleinberg/). Every design technique depends on the problem that you are going to tackle. It is very important to do the exercises in the algorithm books and have feedback from teachers about that.

If there exist a locally optimal choice taht brings the globally optimal solution you can use a greedy algorithm.

If the problem has optimal substructure, you can use dynamic programming.